# yii2 how to deny access Yii::$app->db in view

Tags: security, yii2

We have a development team and I want the developer who focuses on the views will not be able to do retrieving,updating,deleting directly using Yii::$app->db. Every database operation in view must be done via a proper model object. 
How to? Thanks.

Comment: I believe that this is the main reason why many frameworks use templating engines like Blade in Laravel (correct me if I'm wrong). As long as Yii2 views are PHP files, they can access any static/global variables that other PHP files do (controllers,models..). In case of Yii2, it's just the way how framework is built..

Comment: There has no way to unset read-only Yii::$app->db, you can review code by validating the view files to find out 'Yii::$app->db' after developer commits the code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, so I'll write it as an answer.
There are templating engines like Twig that can be plugged in to Yii2. Here is the link to [GitHub Twig Extension](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-twig).
Even though you **can** write php functions in Twig templates, you try to **restrict** yourself and your team with template syntax. So simply saying

```
<?php echo $var ?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>
```

will be written as

```
{{ var }}
{{ var|escape }}
{{ var|e }}         {# shortcut to escape a variable #}
```

So, considering we refuse from PHP tags and use only template syntax, it can be said for sure that noone will/could call `Yii::$app->db` in `{{ }}`

Comment: Thanks to all. Twig extension of yii2 exposes {{app}} automatically and that make possible for developer of views to destroy database.